# Best practices using Javascript prototypes

Tags: javascript, function-prototypes

I know there is a lot of material available on using prototypes but there seem to be a lot of different suggested methods and I'm trying to find mine. I'm really just looking for feedback on the structure below and if you'd see anything issues with it. Thanks in advance.

```
function Class(){}

Class.prototype = {
    MethodOne: function() {

    },
    MethodTwo: function() {

    },
    MethodThree: function() {

   }
}
```

Comment: To answer your question, it looks syntax-correct. But it all depends on your use case. Are you trying to make this into an Object that you would eventually inherit to other objects?

Comment: One you figure out what is your objective with prototypes, update your question with details and notify in comments.

Answer (score 2):

Overall perfect! This is how I create my classes too. Here are a few minor edits:

```
function Class() {
   return this;
}

Class.prototype = {
    methodOne: function() {

    },
    methodTwo: function() {

    },
    methodThree: function() {

   }
}
```

1) Changed the method names to start with lowercase. Just for convention.
2) Made your constructor return this (the newly create object).
3) Once you have created the Class you can use it like:

```
 var obj = new Class();  
 obj.methodOne();
```

Comment: There is no need to put `return this` in constructor. It's a default behaviour. But it's good to know, that constructor can return different object than `this` but it cannot return primitive value.

Answer (score 2):

You're example is really simple and syntax correct. However, I'd like to share my thoughts with you.

First of all, you completely replace prototype object of your `Class` constructor. It's fine, but you lose reference to constructor from objects created with `Class`. Using you code:

```
var a = new Class();
a.constructor; // => function Object() { [native code] }
```

Wouldn't it be better if `constructor` property points to `Class` as it's a real constructor? To fix it, you need to add `constructor` property to `Class` prototype. Like: `Class.prototype.constructor = Class`.

Secondly, I usually see object methods starting from lower case letter. It's rather a convention, but that's how all native object's methods are defined. For instance, look at methods defined in default `Date` object (`Date.prototype.*`). All of them start with lower case letter.